# VB 2013, modify word document property/custom property

Tags: vb.net

I wish to make an add-in to update word document properties. I’m all ready to go with the addin / ribbon / etc. as I have other ribbon functions that are working. I used the MSVS wizard to create the word ribbon project.

I’m stuck on how to; access the active word document, and access the properties/custom properties. I can’t figure out the; declarations, calls, library, etc. I have not been able to make any of the MSDN samples work…. I’m totally missing something.

For example: ‘ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties’ does not work.

Disclaimer - I’m not a coder. I had this all working with vba, I’m trying to port it over to vb. I’m also still reading through the posted help, and trying samples.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Kind regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learned some more.
I no longer need the:

```
Imports moDoc = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
```

Using the Office.Core. rather than the Office.Core.Interop

```
Dim Prop As Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperty
Dim oBuiltInProperties As Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperties
Dim oCustomProperties As Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperties

oBuiltInProperties = DirectCast(Globals.DocSelect.Application.ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties, Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperties)
oCustomProperties = DirectCast(Globals.DocSelect.Application.ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties, Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperties)

For Each Prop In oBuiltInProperties
    'do stuff
    Prop.Name = sx
    sy=Prop.Value.ToString
next

'create properties
sx="New Property"
sy="New Property Value"
oCustomProperties.Add(sx, False, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoDocProperties.msoPropertyTypeString, sy)
```

All works now.

Answer (score 0):

I got it figured.

Outside the module declare:

```
Imports moDoc = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
```

Within the sub - This associates the open app with an object:

```
Dim oActiveApp As moDoc.Application
oActiveApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
```

Now to associate the open app as a document:

```
Dim mocCustProperties As Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperties
Dim odpProp As Office.DocumentProperty
```

Now odpProp is an available to read/add properties:

```
For Each odpProp In mocCustProperties
  If odpProp.Name = “something” Then
   ‘do dtuff
  End If
Next
```

There must be a way to do this by referencing the active document as a document rather than an application, but I was unable to make this work.
Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Drat - missed a couple lines above - please ignore.

I got it figured.
Outside the module declare:

```
Imports moDoc = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
```

Within the sub, This associated the open app with the object

```
Dim oActiveApp As moDoc.Application
oActiveApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
oDocCustomProperty = oActiveApp.ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties
```

Now to associate the open app as a document

```
Dim mocCustProperties As Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperties
Dim odpProp As Office.DocumentProperty
mocCustProperties = CType(oDocCustomProperty, Office.DocumentProperties)
```

Now odpProp is an available to read/add propoeties

```
For Each odpProp In mocCustProperties
  If odpProp.Name = “something” Then
    ‘do dtuff
  End If
Next
```